# Debugging error in custom module of Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom module in Magento for displaying custom button in admin panel of customizable product in that I have called on click event, after clicking on the button it will gives the alert box with product Id and Product variation. It is showing the ID of the product but while I am trying to debug the code it gives the error of:
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Pricing\ModulePrice\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\furniturestore\app\code\Pricing\ModulePrice\block\AdminHtml\Product\Edit\Button\Pricing.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\furniturestore\app\code\Pricing\ModulePrice\block\AdminHtml\Product\Edit\Button\Pricing.php on line 8**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your path :

change folder name `block` by `Block`

then it will works as well :)